# SQL-запрос не возвращает одну из строк при группировке

Tags: sql, pdo, select, group-by

Ситуация очень простая.

Есть таблица на три поля — name, text, time.

При обычном запросе SELECT возвращает все строки, а вот при наличии в нём группировки по времени одну из строк не выводит. Сам запрос:

```
SELECT msgtime, text FROM talk
WHERE msgtime > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY 
GROUP BY msgtime;
```

Строка:

```
testestest test test "{{Test | ~~~~}} __NOINDEX__"? test
```

Данные помещаю в таблицу так (PDO PHP):

```
$q = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO talk (name, text) VALUES (:name, :text)');
$q->execute(array(':name' => $_POST['username'], ':text' => $_POST['text']));
```

Что я делаю не так? Как нужно?

Comment: `одну из строк не выводит` - какую? может тестовые данные приведёте?

Comment: @СергейМишин я ж привёл проблемную строку.

Comment: А при наличии группировки (не соответствующей стандарту SQL) из группы с равным msgtime будет выведена только одна, причём случайная, запись. Остальные вполне ожидаемо "пропадут".

Comment: *я ж привёл проблемную строку* Неправда. В ней в упор не видать значения поля msgtime...

Comment: @akina msgtime — это DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. Спасибо, так и есть: две записи с равным msgtime.

Comment: И чё? Если ты приводишь "проблемную строку" - в ней должны быть ДВА поля. Причём первое - это как минимум дата, а то и дата-время. Что в приведённой строке тупо отсутствует.

Comment: @Turambar А зачем нужен group by, если вы ожидаете что поле группировки будет уникальным и количество строк не изменится ?